# Problems trying to use Slim 3 with Doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, slim

I get the following message:

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details

Type: Error
Message: Class 'App\Action\InterventionsAction' not found
File: /var/www/html/ws_slim/public/index.php
Line: 53
Trace

#0 [internal function]: Closure->{closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#1 /var/www/html/ws_slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/Strategies/RequestResponse.php(41): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#2 /var/www/html/ws_slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(344): Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse->__invoke(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#3 /var/www/html/ws_slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(122): Slim\Route->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#4 /var/www/html/ws_slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(316): Slim\Route->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#5 /var/www/html/ws_slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(476): Slim\Route->run(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#6 /var/www/html/ws_slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(122): Slim\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#7 /var/www/html/ws_slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(370): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#8 /var/www/html/ws_slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(295): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#9 /var/www/html/ws_slim/public/index.php(59): Slim\App->run()
#10 {main}
```

My index file is like this:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use App\Action\InterventionsAction;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$app = new \Slim\App([
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true
    ]
]);
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello,, $name");

    return $response;
});
$app->get('/api/interventions', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $int = new InterventionsAction($em);

    $response->getBody()->write("Hello,, ");

    return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

and InterventionsAction is like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Action;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

final class InterventionsAction
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function fetch($request, $response, $args)
    {
        $interventions = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\Interventions')->findAll();
        $interventions = array_map(
            function ($interventions) {
                return $interventions->getArrayCopy();
            },
            $interventions
        );
        return $response->withJSON($interventions);
    }

}
```

File Tree:

```
├── cli-config.php
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── CONTRIBUTING.md
├── EXPORT
│   ├── Companies.php
│   ├── CompaniesPlansPayments.php
│   ├── CompaniesPlans.php
│   ├── DepartmentsCoordinators.php
│   ├── Departments.php
│   ├── InterventionclasificationDetails.php
│   ├── Interventionclasifications.php
│   ├── Interventionrelations.php
│   ├── Interventions.php
│   ├── InterventiontypesCompanies.php
│   ├── Interventiontypes.php
│   ├── Locations.php
│   ├── LocationTypes.php
│   ├── Managementreview.php
│   ├── Managementreviewrelations.php
│   ├── Plans.php
│   ├── ServicelinesManagers.php
│   ├── Servicelines.php
│   ├── Users.php
│   └── Usertypes.php
├── logs
│   ├── app.log
│   └── README.md
├── nbproject
│   ├── private
│   │   └── private.properties
│   ├── project.properties
│   └── project.xml
├── phpunit.xml
├── public
│   └── index.php
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── Action
│   │   └── InterventionsAction.php
│   ├── dependencies.php
│   ├── Entity
│   │   ├── Companies.php
│   │   ├── CompaniesPlansPayments.php
│   │   ├── CompaniesPlans.php
│   │   ├── DepartmentsCoordinators.php
│   │   ├── Departments.php
│   │   ├── InterventionclasificationDetails.php
│   │   ├── Interventionclasifications.php
│   │   ├── Interventionrelations.php
│   │   ├── Interventions.php
│   │   ├── InterventiontypesCompanies.php
│   │   ├── Interventiontypes.php
│   │   ├── Locations.php
│   │   ├── LocationTypes.php
│   │   ├── Managementreview.php
│   │   ├── Managementreviewrelations.php
│   │   ├── Plans.php
│   │   ├── ServicelinesManagers.php
│   │   ├── Servicelines.php
│   │   ├── Users.php
│   │   └── Usertypes.php
│   ├── middleware.php
│   ├── routes.php
│   └── settings.php
├── templates
│   └── index.phtml
├── tests
│   └── Functional
│       ├── BaseTestCase.php
│       └── HomepageTest.php
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    ├── bin
    │   ├── doctrine -> ../doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine
    │   ├── doctrine-dbal -> ../doctrine/dbal/bin/doctrine-dbal
    │   ├── doctrine.php -> ../doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine.php
    │   └── phpunit -> ../phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
    ├── composer
    │   ├── autoload_classmap.php
    │   ├── autoload_files.php
    │   ├── autoload_namespaces.php
    │   ├── autoload_psr4.php
    │   ├── autoload_real.php
    │   ├── ClassLoader.php
    │   ├── installed.json
    │   └── LICENSE
    ├── container-interop
    │   └── container-interop
    ├── doctrine
    │   ├── annotations
    │   ├── cache
    │   ├── collections
    │   ├── common
    │   ├── dbal
    │   ├── inflector
    │   ├── instantiator
    │   ├── lexer
    │   └── orm
    ├── monolog
    │   └── monolog
    ├── myclabs
    │   └── deep-copy
    ├── nikic
    │   └── fast-route
    ├── phpdocumentor
    │   ├── reflection-common
    │   ├── reflection-docblock
    │   └── type-resolver
    ├── phpspec
    │   └── prophecy
    ├── phpunit
    │   ├── php-code-coverage
    │   ├── php-file-iterator
    │   ├── php-text-template
    │   ├── php-timer
    │   ├── php-token-stream
    │   ├── phpunit
    │   └── phpunit-mock-objects
    ├── pimple
    │   └── pimple
    ├── psr
    │   ├── container
    │   ├── http-message
    │   └── log
    ├── sebastian
    │   ├── code-unit-reverse-lookup
    │   ├── comparator
    │   ├── diff
    │   ├── environment
    │   ├── exporter
    │   ├── global-state
    │   ├── object-enumerator
    │   ├── recursion-context
    │   ├── resource-operations
    │   └── version
    ├── slim
    │   ├── php-view
    │   └── slim
    ├── symfony
    │   ├── console
    │   ├── debug
    │   ├── polyfill-mbstring
    │   └── yaml
    └── webmozart
        └── assert
```

So my question is maybe I setted bad some configuration values or is there something missing I should be looking for?

Comment: Could should show us directory structure and autoloader configuration (composer.json)?

Comment: How could I show you the full directory here? and I installed them separatedly, first I got Slim and then installed the doctrine via command prompt so I did not got composer.json file for this

Comment: This is a bit of a blind guess, admittedly, but curious if you have better luck by moving the `require 'vendor/autoload.php` above the use statements? I may well be wrong, but in any case, the error message states that the class `App\Action\InterventionsAction` cannot be found, so I think this is more of a directory structure/file naming/autoloading issue than an issue with Doctrine. Should help you zero in on the problem area, at least.

Comment: You can use `tree`, like `tree -L 3` and paste part of that (without `vendor` dir) into edited question. I can see you have generated autoload ( required `vendor/autoload.php`), how exactly you got doctrine installed? Usually autoload is generated automatically by composer, and you need that to let application use your classes.

Comment: How does composer.json look like? Have you run composer dump-autoload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your autoloader can't find the files. You should search for the `"autoload"` section in your composer.json and put something like the following in there:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4: {
        "App\\": "src/",
    }
}
```

This assumes that your directory src/ only contains classes from the App-namespace. So src/Action/InterventionAction.php expects to contain a class with the namespace `App\Action\InterventionAction`. For your tests you might want to do the equivalent in the "autoload-dev"-section.

You will also have to run a `composer install` or `composer update --lock` to ensure the autoloader is updated with the new information.

You might also want to read the autoloading PSRs to know how to resolve file names to classes and the composer docs:

- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/ (outdated)
- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload